# make - ontopic or SO

Tags: discussion, scope

I know `make` has long been a unix tool, but me thinks it's too close to programming (at least anything beyond how do I build software X). [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/makefile-examples-and-or-templates) prompted this, I think it should be closed... opinions?

Comment: the link is no longer available

Comment: @tshepang that's because the question was closed... point? technically if you have enough rep, you can still view it

Comment: Considering that the reference to that link isn't really important to the Question, and that the rest of us have puny reps, can you remove it (the sentence).

Comment: Did you mean closed/deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say - depends:

- "How to create Makefile for program" and similar goes to stackoverflow
- "How to build in parallel with `make`" (answer `make -j2`) and similar is on topic