# Please add a reference to Stack Overflow in the site FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

As far as I can tell, there's a consensus that programming questions belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). This should be indicated the first section of the FAQ. Here's a wording proposal:

> If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Previous Meta discussions:

- [Unix C API calls ontopic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic)
- [What to do about programming questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/576/what-to-do-about-programming-questions)
- [Is shell scripting in perl in range of this site?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/is-shell-scripting-in-perl-in-range-of-this-site)
- [Non Standard CLI tools - A ruby tool question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/non-standard-cli-tools-a-ruby-tool-question)
- [make - ontopic or SO](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/make-ontopic-or-so)

Comment: huh, used to be that the trilogy sites were all listed in the FAQ, they've changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[status-completed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/3258/revisions#rev-arrow-ec3a0232-ee56-4b7a-a3e2-15e592b52bfa)